# How to create Entity class for fetching data from two diff Tables?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```sql
select * from city join countrylanguage on  
city.CountryCode=countrylanguage.CountryCode  
order by city.ID;
```

[image]

Here are my query and responce how to create entity for those to tables and repository also

Answer (score 0):

Create two different entity classes for each table and define a relation accordingly.

Comment: thats what i asked, how to map entity relation